# How to merge different type of list as one in Python

Tags: python, list, merge, tuples

I have a list with multiple values which looks like below:

```
list_A = [('Text1',2,3),('Text2',2,45),('Text3',2,23),('Text4',2,0)]
```

Let's say it contains 4 items with 3 variables in each. And I have another list with the same number of items, but one variable for each, which looks like this:

```
list_B = [7,3,3,9]
```

I've been trying to merge them, and the only thing I can get so far is:

```
zip(list_A, list_B)
>>[(('Text1',2,3),7), (('Text2',2,45),3), (('Text3',2,0),3), (('Text4',2,3),9)]

tuple(zip(list_A, list_B)
>>((('Text1',2,3),7), (('Text2',2,45),3), (('Text3',2,0),3), (('Text4',2,3),9))
```

The final result should be in this format:

```
new_list = [('Text1',2,3,7),('Text2',2,45,7),('Text3',2,23,7),('Text4',2,0,9)]
```

Comment: `[(*x, y) for x, y in zip(list_A, list_B)]`

Comment: @vaultah is this python 3? You're solution is `invalid syntax` in python 2.7

Comment: @ppasler I know, it works in Python 3.5 and newer.

Answer (score 2):

Tuples can be added to form a new tuple, so you should form a tuple with the element from list_B:

```
>>> list_A = [('Text1',2,3),('Text2',2,45),('Text3',2,23),('Text4',2,0)]
>>> list_B = [7,3,3,9]
>>> [t+(e,) for t,e in zip(list_A, list_B)]
[('Text1', 2, 3, 7), ('Text2', 2, 45, 3), ('Text3', 2, 23, 3), ('Text4', 2, 0, 9)]
```

Or, in Python 3.5+ only, you can do:

```
>>> [(*t, e) for t, e in zip(list_A, list_B)]
[('Text1', 2, 3, 7), ('Text2', 2, 45, 3), ('Text3', 2, 23, 3), ('Text4', 2, 0, 9)]
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response!! Appreciated!! :)

Answer (score 1):

You may use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) and list comprehension:

```
list_A = [('Text1',2,3),('Text2',2,45),('Text3',2,23),('Text4',2,0)]
list_B = [7,3,3,9]

print [x + (y,) for x, y in zip(list_A, list_B)]
```

**Note:** `x + y` fails, as `tuple` and `int` can't be concatenated

Comment: Thanks a lot, you just saved my day :)

Answer (score 0):

Python tuples have a trait: they are immutable, but their values may change. This may happen when a tuple holds a reference to any mutable object, such as a list.

Tuple is immutable we can not modify it again: So we recreate this as follows:

```
list_A = [('Text1',2,3),('Text2',2,45),('Text3',2,23),('Text4',2,0)]
list_B = [7,3,3,9]
new_list = [(i[0]+(i[1],)) for i in zip(list_A, list_B)]
or
new_list = [tuple(list(i[0])+[i[1]]) for i in zip(list_A, list_B)]

new_list
[('Text1', 2, 3, 7), ('Text2', 2, 45, 3), ('Text3', 2, 23, 3), ('Text4', 2, 0, 9)]
```

Comment: `tuple([j for j in i[0]]+[i[1]])` is simply terrible. Why do `[j for j in i[0]]` instead of just `list(i[0])`? Why convert tuples to lists just to concatenate them? It's also about 6-7 times slower than `i[0] + (i[1],)` and *far* less readable.